# Asp.Net Mvc 3, jQuery, cross-domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, cross-domain

I have a site "A" and to test cross site posts from site "B" using jQuery I've added this in `Global.asax Application_BeginRequest`

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
```

The post from site "B" looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: rootUrl,
    crossDomain: true,
    data: request.toPostData(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: onsuccess,
    error: onerror
});
```

My problem now is that it lets through two requests to the controller action. One with formvalues and one without.

Of course I only want the last one, which holds the values. I hope anyone could explain and point me to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

to go across domains, you need to use something like jsonp  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: The request does get through with the data.

Answer (score 0):

use dataType:'jsonp' and append your url with '&callback=?'

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType:'jsonp',
    url: rootUrl,
    crossDomain: true,
    data: request.toPostData(),
    success: onsuccess,
    error: onerror
});
```

for more reference http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/

Comment: Just gives `jQuery151042722045979462564_1327352766794 was not called`